# XFBML version of Facebook Like button doesn't work in IE9

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-9, facebook-like, xfbml

I am trying to implement Facebook Like button to my site based on asp.net. It works fine in IE8, Mozilla and Google Chrome but in IE9 it doesn't.

I've tried iframe version, XFBML version, HTML5 version - all of them work fine in Mozilla, IE8, GoogleChrome... but in IE9 I see the same picture for all versions.

For example, when I press Like from page http://ideal.astrum.ua/online-brokerage/software.aspx
I am redirected to =">http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect_to_external_page_widget_loggedin.php?social_plugin=like&external_page_url=http%3A%2F%2Fideal.astrum.ua%2Fonline-brokerage%2Fsoftware.aspx#*=*

where I see an empty page with facebook header on top.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. If you deactivate the protected mode of IE it will work. It's a short but easy solution after hours of headache!